# What is the correct way to declare a class in TypeScript?

Tags: class, typescript

No matter what I try I keep getting "error TS1046: 'declare' modifier required for top level element." What is the proper way to define the following class:

```
declare class File {

    name: string;

    isOpenEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit the 'declare' keyword:

```
class MyFile {

    name: string;

    isOpenEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`declare` is like `extern` in C -- it is used to declare things but not define them.

Comment: The playground complains of "Duplicate identifier 'File'" with this code.

Comment: `File` is a DOM type so it's not a good choice for naming your own class. Substitute with an available name of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript Playground is a great place to learn this kind of thing:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Look for the "Classes" demo.

Specifically, this code seems to work well.

```
export module SomeNamespace { 
    class File {

        name: string;

        isOpenEnabled() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Without the module bit, the compiler complains that File has already been declared.. almost like it's a built-in type.

Comment: That failed for me. I'm running this in WebStorm but it just calls the compiler. Is there a recent change in the compiler I need to get?

Comment: I don't know if it fails. It converts to javascript but I can't test if it's valid javascript because it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It looks like the problem may be WebStorm. I have a question in to them and will update when I get an answer. Thank you for the help - that got me pointed at WebStorm.